# Film or book trilogy about sentient weapons

Tags: story-identification, movie, weapon

I realize this is a somewhat vague question, but I'm working off 20-year-old memories here. Back around 1980 there were three movies released which featured sentient, or at least living, weapons. I remember watching an interview where the man being interviewed said that they were a "loose trilogy" based on something, and that more was planned, but as I said that was 20+ years ago.

The two films I know of are [Hawk the Slayer (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080846/) and [The Archer: Fugitive from the  Empire (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082027/). Hawk wielded the Mindsword, a 2-handed sword that responds to mental commands, and the Archer had the Heartbow, which could only be used by one pure of heart (or something like that). The weapons didn't talk or anything, but were supposedly "alive" to a point. Both stories were set in a generic Dragonlance-style world.

So, here's the question: **What was the third movie in this "trilogy" (if it was one), and were these based on a book series or anything?**

I've glanced through the IMDB cast & crew for both movies, but I'm not seeing any common names, so I have no idea who was giving the interview. It would have been on TV back in the early 80s. I'd pass it off as a kid's wishful thinking except my parents both remember the same thing, so it was apparently something we all saw together back in the day.

Help me, StackExchange... you're my only hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you certain that those two movies you listed are related, beyond the theme of having special weapons?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk_the_Slayer), director [Terry Marcel](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0545169/) stated in a 1980 interview with *Cinefantastique* that he was planning a sequel, called *Hawk - the Destroyer*.  However, that sequel was not made.

Instead, just a couple of years ago (2011) he announced in a [press release](http://www.shockya.com/news/2011/06/10/hawk-the-hunter-the-sequel-to-hawk-the-slayer-in-the-works/),  that he was "bowing to fan pressure" and making a sequel called *Hawk the Hunter*.

I can find no relationship between the *Hawk* franchise and *The Archer*, aside from another person who had a recollection of them being "from the same people" in a [forum](http://www.therpf.com/f45/hawk-slayer-97395/).  However, someone replied that the two movies were from two completely different production companies, and that there was no relation to them.

There was one other movie around that time that featured an "intelligent weapon" in a fantasy setting, though.  [*Krull*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/), released in 1983, featured a protagonist armed with the "Glave", a magical bladed weapon that could be thrown, and would (if I recall correctly) magically aim itself and generally defy physics.

Comment: It's possible that I'm remembering wrong, or that the "loose trilogy" comment I'm remembering referred to a collaborative effort rather than an actual trilogy. If it's the latter, it's highly possible that Krull is the answer. I had originally discounted it because it has a much more "sci-fi" bent to it than the other two, but the Glaive does fit the pattern as a semi-sentient weapon, AND the timing (1983) fits as well. If I don't see a better answer, I'll probably take this one.

Comment: +1; **Krull** is the one I would think of to meet the general criteria, but I have no recollection of any connection with other movies in any kind of trilogy, loose or otherwise.